# Research in redis

Tags: php, symfony, redis

I'm new to `redis` and I'm using it to store for each user some books he's chosen to read til the end of the week. Obviously, user should be able to add/remove/purge his list of books.

Can I take advantage from `redis` to do something like in 'SQL' for instance : `DELETE FROM ....` or to tell if userA has a book in his list ...

> The following code shows how I'm doing to figure out whether a user has a given book already stored

```
 // Storing part
 $books = array(
      array(
          'reference' => 'HKL33432h22',
          'titre'     => 'titre1',
          'auteur'    => 'toto'
      ),
      array(
          'reference' => 'APZO0000NKHD',
          'titre'     => 'titre2',
          'auteur'    => 'titi'
      ),....
 );

 $this->redis->set($userId, serialize($books));

 // Searching part
 $referenceToLookFor = '89OHJLKJFKEJH';
 $found = false;
 $storedBooks = unserialize($this->redis->get($userId));

 foreach ($storedBooks as $i => $storedBook) {
      if ($referenceToLookFor === $storedBook['reference']) {
          $found = true;
      }
 }
```

Is it possible to get `redis` to tell if a user has a book or not through its reference for instance (unique value)

> Used bundle

`"snc/redis-bundle": "1.1.x-dev"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for Redis' [Hash datatype](http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro#hashes). You can put your array of books into a hash which you can then check for existence of a key (reference number for example) with [`HEXISTS`](http://redis.io/commands/hexists), iterate through all books in the hash with [`HSCAN`](http://redis.io/commands/hscan) or delete specific entries with [`HDEL`](http://redis.io/commands/hdel) and add with [`HSET`](http://redis.io/commands/hset).

Keep in mind that Redis doesn't know or care what data you're storing in it's keys, it is entirely key based without any SQL style `WHERE key=value`.

Comment: Another "quick" question as a complement, I'd like to split books into ebooks and books, so when I look for ebook redis must only look into ebooks and vice versa

Comment: You'd need 2 different hashes under different keys.